# Compile mxnet CPP package with mkldnn to support single thread execution without environment variables

Tags: multithreading, mxnet

We are looking for a way to use mxnet CPP lib with a single thread on Linux like systems.
From mxnet documentation and community experience, the only way that  we found  was setting environment variables:

```
export MXNET_ENGINE_TYPE=NaiveEngine
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

But this way is problematic it is not always possible to configure environment variables.

Deeping into the mxnet code
we found that there some preprocessor definitions and CMake flags that can help

```
mxnet  preprocessor definition MXNET_PREDICT_ONLY=1 will enable naiveEngine
mkldnn cmake flag MKLDNN_THREADING=SEQ
```

The questions are:

1)Is it possible to compile mxnet in single-thread mode at all?

2)If it is possible, what minimal number of changes we can do to compile single threading mxnet lib?

3)Is there any other solution to ensure single thread execution of the mxnet neural net model?

Any help will be appreciated.